# How can I refactor to get rid of an instance variable?

Tags: ruby, refactoring

I have tons of methods like this:

```
def lab1
  setup
  business_processing
rescue Exception => e
  handle_error('custom error message for lab1', e)
end

def lab2
  setup
  business_processing
rescue Exception => e
  handle_error('custom errror message for lab2', e)
end
```

I refactored the code above into something like this:

```
def lab1
  with_setup_and_error_handling do
    @error_message = 'error in lab1'
    business_processing
  end
end

def with_setup_and_error_handling(&block)
  setup
  block.call
rescue Exception => e
  handle_error(@error_message, e)
end
```

The new code works but it causes `error_message` to be an instance variable. Is there a better way to refactor it?

When someone looks at the refactored code they see the instance variable, but it is not clear where it is being used so I am not happy with it.

Comment: I think this belongs on the Code Review SE.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put the error message to be a argument of de setup method:

```
def lab1
  with_setup_and_error_handling('error in lab1') do
    business_processing
  end
end

def with_setup_and_error_handling(error_message, &block)
  setup
  block.call
rescue Exception => e
  handle_error(error_message, e)
end
```

Comment: This technically solves the problem but doesn't address the larger issue of how to properly handle having N similar methods with small variations.

Comment: @Wes: The larger issue would have to be handled on a case-by-case basis, there are too many variables for any sort of general solution.

Comment: close enough. Based on other responses it seems there is no good solution. Marking it as acceptable solution.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just passing the error message as an argument to your with_setup_and_error_handling? Seems like an obvious solution to me.

Comment: You could do that as @LBg demonstrated, but the code would still smell

Answer (score 1):

This is an XY Problem*.

The fact that you think you need to "get rid of" an instance variable is a smell that indicates a poor design. In this case, the poor design is state leak caused by improper use/understanding of scope (instance variables). "It doesn't work otherwise" is not sufficient reason to make something an instance variable.

* http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341

Answer (score 1):

If all you are changing is the error message per process then why not refactor the code the following way:

```
def lab(version)
  begin
    setup
    business_processing
  rescue Exception => e
    handle_error("error in lab#{version}", e)
  end
end
```

and if necessary to keep the individual labN methods do the following:

```
def lab1
  self.lab 1
end

def lab2
  self.lab 2
end
```